# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'AppName' in Django

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-apps, django-2.2

I did install django in server. **Instead of installing apps next to the django project folder,  I installed them inside the django project folder.** (I put them next to the `settings.py` and `wsgi.py`)

This is *structure of django* project:

```
BaseFile  
    |__django (Project File)
    |   |___administrator (App)
    |   |    |___ views.py
    |   |    |___ urls.py
    |   |    |___ ...
    |   |
    |   |___blog (App)
    |   |    |___ views.py
    |   |    |___ urls.py
    |   |    |___ ...
    |   |
    |   |___ __init__.py
    |   |___ settings.py 
    |   |___ urls.py
    |   |___ wsgi.py
    |   
    |___ env
    |___ manage.py 
    |___ media
    |___ static
    |___ templates
```

And this is my `settings.py` :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
# MY APPS:
'administrator.apps.AdministratorConfig',
'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
]
```

And when I want to `makemigrations` I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "BaseFile/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "BaseFile/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "BaseFile/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "BaseFile/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "BaseFile/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 116, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'administrator'
```

What is wrong with my codes?

Comment: Could you just show content of administrator.apps ?

Comment: Which file contents should I show? @Debendra

Comment: administrator/apps.py

Comment: `from django.apps import AppConfig


class AdministratorConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'administrator'
` @Debendra

Comment: So then apps are sub package of projects. Import should be done that way. It should be django.administrator. why you doing that? Are there specific reasons or you are just managing the structure? If that's so then you are wrong. Apps shouldn't be sub package of project. App should be independent of project so it could be re used.

Comment: I can't understand. I which line of which file I should put `django.administrator` ? @Debendra

Comment: Ok. So If I copy that apps to one level up, the problem gone? @Debendra

Comment: Add it in administrator.apps.AdminstratorConfig.name.

Comment: Try to define your apps as **'administrator', 'blog'**

Comment: I did change the directory of these apps (one level up) and problem is solve. Thanks @D